# how to pass in multiple properties as parameters and then use them properly?

Tags: c#, generics

I got this generic method;

```
public CompareResult<T> GenericCompare<T>(CompareLogic compareLogic, List<T> OldObject, List<T> NewObject, Func<T, int> DelProperty)
{
    var result = new CompareResult<T>();

    var OldObjectId = OldObject.Select(DelProperty);
    var NewObjectId = NewObject.Select(DelProperty);

    var ObjectAddedId = NewObjectId.Except(OldObjectId);
    var ObjectRemovedId = OldObjectId.Except(NewObjectId);

    var SameOldObject = OldObject.Where(x => !ObjectRemovedId.Contains(DelProperty(x)));
    var SameNewObject = NewObject.Where(x => !ObjectAddedId.Contains(DelProperty(x)));

    var SameObject = SameOldObject.Join(
                                            SameNewObject,
                                            Older => DelProperty(Older),
                                            Newer => DelProperty(Newer),
                                            (Older, Newer) => new { older = Older, newer = Newer }
                                        );

    foreach (var same in SameObject)
    {
        var ObjectCompare = compareLogic.Compare(same.older, same.newer);
        if (!ObjectCompare.AreEqual)
        {
            var Modified = ObjectCompare.Differences.Select(x => x.PropertyName);
            result.ObjectModified.Add(new Tuple<T, T, IEnumerable<string>>(same.older, same.newer, Modified));
        }
    }
    result.ObjectRemoved = OldObject.Where(x => ObjectRemovedId.Contains(DelProperty(x))).ToList();
    result.ObjectAdded = NewObject.Where(x => ObjectAddedId.Contains(DelProperty(x))).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

for the `DelProperty` parameter I can have these combinations;

1. one field, int (current code)
2. two fields, int, int
3. two fields, string, string

the parameter `DelProperty` is like a primary key of the object, what would i need to do to make this code compatible with "composite" primary key? I'm kind of stuck at this point.

the only thing that i can think of is to copy/paste this code twice to implement the 2 missing combinations but I'm afraid that more combinations will come and this could get messy pretty easily

Answer (score 0):

You can add an overload generic in the key type and with a key equality comparer:

```
public CompareResult<T> GenericCompare<T, K>(CompareLogic compareLogic, List<T> OldObject, List<T> NewObject, Func<T, K> DelProperty, IEqualityComparer<K> keyComparer)
{
    var ObjectAddedId = NewObjectId.Except(OldObjectId, keyComparer);
    var ObjectRemovedId = OldObjectId.Except(NewObjectId, keyComparer);
    ...
}
```

then you can update your current method to call the new one:

```
public CompareResult<T> GenericCompare<T>(CompareLogic compareLogic, List<T> OldObject, List<T> NewObject, Func<T, int> DelProperty)
{
    return GenericCompare(compareLogic, OldObject, NewObject, DelProperty, EqualityComparer<int>.Default);
}
```

Comment: you gave me an idea which seem to be working, adding the generic `K`, I can compose the key by passing in a tuple instead of the actual properties. so far this seem to be working. like this `x => new Tuple<string,string>(x.Prefix,x.Code)`